# standardize column names - search for a set of column names and then use the one available for the new standardized columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am preparing and standardizing data. Part of that standardizing column names. I use data.table.

What I want is this: I want to create a new standardized column name (self-defined) and set my code so that it searches a specificed vector of colnames in the original data and if it find any of these colmns then use that to fill in the standardized column name.

I appreciate it might not be clear so here is an example. In teh belwo, I want to create new standardized column name `WEIGHT`. I want to seach colnames in `dat` for any of these (`wt`,`WT`,`WTBL`) and if it finds one of them then use it for the new column `WEIGHT`

```
library(data.table)
library(car)
dat <- as.data.table(mtcars)

dat[, WEIGHT := wt]  #this is what we do normally - but i want to make it semiautomatic so that i search for a vector of column names and use the one that is avalble to fill in the WEIGHT columes.

dat[, WEIGHT := colnames(dat%in%c('wt','WT','WTBL'))] #this is wrong and there where i need help!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably a simpler construction of this, but here's an attempt. The `mget()` attempts to grab each value in order, returning a `NULL` if not found.

Then the first non-`NULL` value is used to overwrite:

```
dat[, WEIGHT := {
    m <- mget(c("WTBL","wt","WT"), ifnotfound=list(NULL))
    m[!sapply(m, is.null)][1]
}]
```

Comment: Hi @thelatemail -  there is a bug in the code - if the first value mget is looking at is not available then it will stop and will not continue to the next value. Is there a way to fix?

Comment: for example; if we have the above as: `dat[, WEIGHT := {
    m <- mget(c("WTBL","wt","WT"), ifnotfound=list(NULL))
    m[!is.null(m)][1]
}]` then it will not work!!

Comment: @Amer - try it now - I was selecting out the `NULLS` inappropriately with `!is.null(m)` when I needed `!sapply(m, is.null)`

Comment: Yep! thnaks for your help!

Comment: Can we put it into a function? i tried this but it didnt work - seems that I am missing somthing? `search.col <- function(keywords){
    m <- mget(c("WTBL","wt","WT"), ifnotfound=list(NULL)); m[!sapply(m, is.null)][1]
} 
dat[, WEIGHT := search.col(keywords=c('wt,WT,WEIGHT'))]`

Comment: You didn't reference `keywords` in your function anywhere.

Comment: Sorry - I meant this `search.col <- function(keywords){
    m <- mget(keywords, ifnotfound=list(NULL)); m[!sapply(m, is.null)][1]
}

dat[, WEIGHT := search.col(keywords=c('wt,WT,WEIGHT'))]`  which has something missing that is making it not working?

Comment: `search.col(keywords=c('wt','WT','WEIGHT'))`  - you were putting everything in as one string rather than as a vector of possibilities.

Comment: My bad again but still with that corrected, I am getting this error that makes it not working peroperly: `Warning message:
In `[.data.table`(dat, , `:=`(WEIGHT, search.col(keywords = c("wt",  :
  Column 'WEIGHT' does not exist to remove`

Comment: @Amer - is there a circumstance where *none* of the variables are present? Because it would fall over in that case.

Comment: No. I am using the same example and it does have `'wt'` in the data

Comment: Your code works fine though - it is my function that is not doing the right thing!